# how to use a counter when refering to a specific edit box

Tags: delphi

Here's what I'm trying to do,

```
for y:=1 to 8 do
  begin
    if edittexty.text = '1' then
        input1[y]:=true
    else
        input1[y]:=false;
```

The problem is, delphi recognizes edity.text as a whole variable

All I want to do is compare 8 editboxes with 1's and set an array value to true/false. I'm trying to loop the whole process in order to avoid writing out edit1.text, edit2.text etc. Any ideas ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Lots of ways to do this.  What version of delphi?

Comment: Put your edit controls into an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var
  LComponent : TComponent;
begin
  for y:=1 to 8 do
  begin
    LComponent := Self.FindComponent('edit' + IntToStr(y));
    if (not Assigned(LComponent)) or (not (LComponent is TCustomEdit)) then
      continue;

    input1[y] := (LComponent as TCustomEdit).Text = '1';
  end;
end;
```

Where `Self` is the form that holds all the edits.

Comment: I'd write this as `if (LComponent <> nil) and (LComponent is TCustomEdit) then` and without using `Continue`. It's much shorter that way.

Comment: This solution trades memory for CPU time (in comparison to mine), I prefer to use memory, but I guess it's a matter of taste and might not make a any noticable difference with eight controls.

Comment: How the `if` statement is done is a personal preference thing. My preference is how I did it, as if you want to add more processing (extra lines), you don't have to wrap the line in a `begin`/`end`.

Comment: What is the saying - `Optimisation is the root of all evil`. When speed becomes an issue, then fix it :)

Comment: I just don't like code with lot's of "not" in it. I like to have a more positive attitude.

Comment: The optimization statement is also quite true, many programmers optimize way too much where it doesn't belong / isn't necessary ...

Comment: It is possible to remove one of the `not` : `if (not (Assigned(LComponent) and (LComponent is TCustomEdit))) then continue;`

Answer (score 4):

Using `TList<T>`:

```
uses
  System.Generic.Collections;

var
  Edits : TList<TEdit>;
  I     : Integer;
begin
  Edits := TList<TEdit>.Create;
  try
    Edits.AddRange([
      Edit1,
      Edit2,
      // etc.
      Edit8
    );
    // You must be careful with array bounds here, Inputs and Edits must have the same length
    Assert(Length(Inputs) = Length(Edits));
    for I := 0 to Edits.Count - 1 do
      Inputs[I] := Edits[I].Text = '1';
  finally
    Edits.Free;
  end;
end;
```

For older Delphi versions without Generics (using a `TList`):

```
var
  Edits : TList;
  I     : Integer;
begin
  Edits := TList.Create;
  try
    Edits.Add(Edit1);
    Edits.Add(Edit2);
    // etc.
    // You must be careful with array bounds here, Inputs and Edits must have the same length
    Assert(Length(Inputs) = Length(Edits));
    for I := 0 to Edits.Count - 1 do
      Inputs[I] := TEdit(Edits[I]).Text = '1';
  finally
    Edits.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Using `array of T` (which can also be written as `TArray<T>` in newer Delphi versions):

```
var
  Edits : array of TEdit;
  I     : Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Edits, 8);
  Edits[0] := Edit1;
  Edits[1] := Edit2;
  // etc.
  // You must be careful with array bounds here, Inputs and Edits must have the same length
  Assert(Length(Inputs) = Length(Edits));
  for I := 0 to Edits.Count - 1 do
    Inputs[I] := Edits[I].Text = '1';
end;
```

Using `TArray<T>` with `TArray<T>.Create`:

```
var
  Edits : TArray<TEdit>;
  I     : Integer;
begin
  Edits := TArray<TEdit>.Create(
    Edit1,
    Edit2,
    // etc.
    Edit8
  );
  // You must be careful with array bounds here, Inputs and Edits must have the same length
  Assert(Length(Inputs) = Length(Edits));
  for I := 0 to Edits.Count - 1 do
    Inputs[I] := Edits[I].Text = '1';
end;
```

Using `TDictionary<K, V>`:

```
uses
  System.Generic.Collections;

type
  TInput = class
  public
    Active: Boolean;
  end;

var
  InputByEdit : TObjectDictionary<TEdit, TInput>;
  Pair        : TPair<TEdit, TInput>;
begin
  InputByEdit := TObjectDictionary<TEdit, TInput>.Create([doOwnsValues]);
  try
    InputByEdit.Add(Edit1, TInput.Create);
    InputByEdit.Add(Edit2, TInput.Create);
    // etc.
    for Pair in InputByEdit do
      Pair.Value.Active := Pair.Key.Text = '1';
  finally
    InputByEdit.Free;
  end;
end;
```

There are several ways to improve this:

- Make the container a class member and populate it once at creation time.
- Use `Components` and `ComponentCount` to populate the container dynamically.

You might also consider using `TCheckBox` instead of `TEdit` so you don't have to parse the `Text` and also to improve usability.

Comment: +1 for You might also consider using TCheckBox instead of TEdit so you don't have to parse the Text and also to improve usability.

Comment: +1 (and I actually cast the vote!) In XE7 I think you can write: `Edits := [Edit1, Edit2, ..., Edit8];`